# How to make duplicate exclusion for crawled links?

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
async def test():
old_links = open("old_links.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")

while True:
    base_url = 'https://www.cnbc.com/world/' async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as sess: async with sess.get(base_url, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) as res: 
    text = await res.text() 
    soup = bs(text, 'lxml')

    title = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"LatestNews-container"}).a.text.strip() 
    link = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"LatestNews-container"}).a["href"]

    if link not in old_links: 
        print(f"title : {title}") 
        print(f"link : {link}") 
        f = open("old_links.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") 
        f.write(f"{link}\n") 
        f.close()

    else: print("No update")


await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

The site above is an example. i'm making a discord bot via python, and i'm making a crawling bot for some sites that don't support mailing service. i'm not major learning python. i just succeeded in creating this code through search and simple study, i maded a list with old_links = [] and applied it and used it. but when i reboot the discord bot, the posts that were crawled in the past are sent back to discord as messages. to solve this, i save the link of the post what bot sent the message to as a .txt file and keep it on my computer, and compare it with the link in the text file when the bot runs every certain time. i'm trying to implement sending function. i saving the crawled links in the .txt file was successful, but the function to compare the links stored in the .txt file was not implemented. how should i write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be opening `old_links` as a text file without reading its contents. Assuming your existing links are separated by a new line, you can use

```py
old_links = []
with open("old_links.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    old_links = file.read().splitlines()
```

to create a `list` out of the old links read from the file. The `with` block makes sure the file is closed properly immediately after execution and limits its scope.

When you want to add a new link, simply append the new link to the array like so:

```py
old_links.append(new_link)
```

Make sure you write the new lines back to the file after every update so that your changes save correctly:

```py
with open("old_links.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(old_links))
```